# Add UITextFieldDelegate in cocos2d?

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

There are a lot of similar questions and answers, but they don't solve the main problem: how to properly add any text field in cocos2d with its workable delegate.

For example if I create UITextfield and simply add it to [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] then it will call textFieldShouldReturn: method only. No more methods doesn't work, even textViewDidBeginEditing:

I gave the same result with using of separate view and UITextField. I also tried to create a separate UIViewController to use its view with UITextField but it even make my app falling down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that UITextFieldDelegate and UITextViewDelegate have some similar mehods, and I used some methods from the second delegate. Example:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Of course I wrote (UITextView *)textField at the end.

Answer (score 1):

1: Make sure your `CCNode` contains the `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
@interface MyLayer : CCLayer <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

2: Init the UITextField as per usual:

```
UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight)];
            nameField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            nameField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:24];
            nameField.text = @"Enter Name";
            nameField.delegate = self;
            nameField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            nameField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            nameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

3: Add the field to the `CCDirector` view:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:nameField];
```

4: Implement the `UITextField` delegates in your `CCNode`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: thanks. You didn't solved my problem but I found my mistake